# Error when trying to post data to rest API using an appscript

Tags: javascript, rest

I am struggling to write an appscript to post data to sage accounting API

I am trying to save a new customer to sage accounting software through the API. When I use postman it works. I cant get the appscript to work though.

The following is the code I am using:

```
function postDataToSageOneAPI() {
  // Define your API endpoint URL
  var apiUrl = 'https://resellers.accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/Customer/Save';

  // Define  authentication credentials
  var username = 'myusername';
  var password = 'mypassword';

  // Extract the CompanyId from the URL
  var companyId = "14787";

  // Define the API key
  var apiKey = "{####################################}";

  // Create the payload data you want to send as JSON
  var payload = '{"Name": "string1", "Email": "string2"}'; // Assuming this is a valid JSON string

  // Add the API key and CompanyId to the URL as query parameters
  apiUrl += '?apikey=' + apiKey + '&CompanyId=' + companyId;

  // Define the headers for the request
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  // Configure the options for the request
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': payload,
  };

  // Make the POST request to the Sage One API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);

  // Check the response status code
  var statusCode = response.getResponseCode();

  // Handle the response
  if (statusCode === 200) {
    var responseBody = response.getContentText();
    // Process the responseBody as needed
    Logger.log('Response Body: ' + responseBody);
  } else {
    // Handle errors or other status codes
    Logger.log('Error: ' + statusCode);
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Exception: Invalid argument:
> [https://resellers.accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/Customer/Save?apikey={#####################}&CompanyId=14787](https://resellers.accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/Customer/Save?apikey=%7B#####################%7D&CompanyId=14787)
> postDataToSageOneAPI    @ Code.gs:35

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the following

encodeURIComponent for apikey and companyid

Use cases for encodeURIComponent

User has submitted values in a form that may be in a string format and need to be passed in, such as URL fields.
Need to accept query string parameters in order to make GET requests.

here is the modified code

```
var apiUrl = 'https://resellers.accounting.sageone.co.za/api/2.0.0/Customer/Save?apikey=' + encodeURIComponent(apiKey) + '&CompanyId=' + encodeURIComponent(companyId);
```